# PySpark - using functions with variables instead of data frames as parameters raising exception

Tags: pyspark

I am new to Python, so it might be something obvious. I am trying to do some transformation on a string variables (or even literals), but any function I use fails with:

> com.incorta.api.exceptions.DataException: INC_03070101: Transformation error [Error An error occurred while calling o74.**getnewargs**. Trace:
> py4j.Py4JException: Method **getnewargs**([]) does not exist
> ('Py4JError', ':', Py4JError(u'An error occurred while calling o74.**getnewargs**. Trace:\npy4j.Py4JException: Method **getnewargs**([]) does not exist\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:318)\n\tat py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.getMethod(ReflectionEngine.java:326)\n\tat py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:274)\n\tat py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)\n\tat py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)\n\tat py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)\n\n',))

Spark version 2.4.7

Sample code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring
objectName = substring("fullFieldString", 1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what you try to achieve but the usage of substring in pyspark is as following.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.substring.html

Comment: I am parsing XML (which is stored in a table). I pull one attribute into a string variable. Then I am trying to split that string into 3. How to achieve it?
Sample I gave was simplified without any variable, but just string constant. Does it mean all these functions will only work on data frames?
BTW - is my usage not following that documentation? I am providing string, start position and length.

Answer (score 0):

I should probably do some Python basics course first :) I found my answer here:

[Strings slicing in Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_strings_slicing.asp)

```
schemaName = fullFieldString[:fullFieldString.find('.')]
```

It seems that variables have completely separate functions set and majority of references are describing data frames functions